# GROUP BY, COUNT() in joined tables of MySQL query

Tags: mysql, join, count, group-by

I'm looking to count all my projects by category within a set of two dates.
I've got a main table:

Table **project**

```
+-----+-------------+------------------+
| uid |    name     | project_category |
+-----+-------------+------------------+
|   1 | Testproject |                1 |
|   2 | Anothertest |                2 |
|   3 | Fietspomp   |                1 |
|   4 | Caramba     |                1 |
+-----+-------------+------------------+
```

Whose categories are stored in **project_category**

```
+-----+-------------+
| uid |    name     |
+-----+-------------+
|   1 | Automotive  |
|   2 | Hospitality |
|   3 | Other       |
+-----+-------------+
```

My dates however, are stored in the following table. There can be more dates (shifts) per project. I'm looking to find only the earliest date (shift) per project: I need to filter on the start date (= the first shift) of each project.

Table **project_shift**

```
+-----+-------------+------------+
| uid | project_uid |    date    |
+-----+-------------+------------+
|   1 |           1 | 2015-05-03 |
|   2 |           2 | 2015-05-02 |
|   3 |           2 | 2015-06-04 |
|   4 |           1 | 2015-03-08 |
|   5 |           1 | 2015-08-08 |
+-----+-------------+------------+
```

I've been looking high and low, but my counts keep getting messed up. This is what I tried:

```
SELECT pc.name as category, p.name, count(p.uid)
FROM project p
INNER JOIN project_category pc ON pc.uid = p.project_category
INNER JOIN project_shift ps    ON ps.project_uid = p.uid AND ps.date BETWEEN "2015-01-01" AND "2015-08-08"
GROUP BY pc.uid
```

Also:

```
SELECT    pc.name as category, count(pc.uid) as amount
FROM      project p
LEFT JOIN project_category pc ON pc.uid = p.project_category
WHERE     (SELECT MIN(date) FROM project_shift ps WHERE ps.project_uid = p.uid LIMIT 1) BETWEEN :date_from AND :date_to
GROUP BY  pc.uid
```

This last one comes close, but still counts 29 projects too many.

What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT: The desired result is the following (dummy data)**

```
+-------------+--------+
|  category   | amount |
+-------------+--------+
| Automotive  |     70 |
| Hospitality |     22 |
| Other       |      2 |
+-------------+--------+
```

Comment: I don't fully understand the question, but I think it could be as simple as using `COUNT DISTINCT`. Try replacing the `count(p.uid)` in each of the queries you posted above with `count(distinct p.uid)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query seems almost right. Only, it is project_category you should be selecting from and project which should be outer joined (such as to get categories that have zero projects). So it is projects (i.e. `p.uid`) you want to count per category.

Then your LIMIT clause makes no sense. MIN(date) gives you one record with the minimum date for the project. No need for a LIMIT clause here.

```
SELECT    pc.name as category, count(p.uid) as amount
FROM      project_category pc 
LEFT JOIN project p ON p.project_category = pc.uid
WHERE     (SELECT MIN(date) FROM project_shift ps WHERE ps.project_uid = p.uid)
            BETWEEN :date_from AND :date_to
GROUP BY  pc.uid;
```

Answer (score 1):

You also need to include project_category from the project table in the group by:

```
SELECT pc.name as category,  count(p.project_category)
FROM project p, project_category pc, project_shift ps
where pc.uid = p.project_category
and ps.project_uid = p.uid
and ps.date BETWEEN '1/1/2015' and '8/8/2015'
group by pc.uid, p.project_category
```

Should do it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but your query gives me way too many results per category. Possibly because there are multiple project_shift entries per project. Could you have another look?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT    pc.name as category, count(pc.uid) as amount
FROM      project p
INNER JOIN project_category pc ON pc.uid = p.project_category
INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT MIN(`date`) AS `date`, project_uid FROM project_shift 
        WHERE `date` BETWEEN :date_from AND :date_to
        GROUP BY project_uid
    ) AS ps ON (ps.project_uid = pc.uid) 
GROUP BY  pc.uid
```

Comment: Thanks but this yields no results. I'll investigate further to see if something is wrong on my end.